# API Postman error: "The PATCH method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD"

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I create custom Request which named "StoreUser" for custom validation rules for `store` and `update` methods. For `store` method when i using `POST` method in Postman it's all working good. But for `PATCH/PUT` method i catch error: "*The PATCH method is not supported for this route*".

Supported methods: GET, HEAD". My URL for PATCH method: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/44`
Using debagger, i found that the problem occurs when custom `Request "StoreUser"` start return array rules in `rules()` method.
Below my code. Only error occurs in `PATCH/PUT` method, `POST` it's ok

ApiResource

```
Route::apiResource('users', 'UserController');
```

UserController update/store methods

```
public function store(StoreUser $request)
{
    $request->validated();

    $password = User::hashPassword($request->get('password'));
    $request->merge(['password' => $password]);

    $user = User::create($request->all());
    return response()->json($user, 201);
}

public function update(StoreUser $request, $id)
{
    $request->validated();
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->update($request->all());
    return response()->json($user, 200);
}
```

Custom Request StoreUser

```
public function rules()
{
    return [ // in this place error occurs ONLY IN PATCH/PUT methods
        'name' => 'required|min:5',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|max:50'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding **_method="PATCH"** in the body of the request. The type of request should be POST.

Comment: Yeah, it's return me 200 code, but i dont know why, btn nothing update
http://i.imgur.com/j4H8oPQ.png

Comment: Try to just return your inputs as a response and comment everything else just to see if data is being passed as intended.

Comment: if I understand you correctly, i create using post method new user and copy all json data, after that i put it all i paste it in PUT/PATCH methods and catch the same error. Code break when in StoreUser rules() method call return of rules, if for expamle i add dd(1); before return postman return me that 1

Comment: use the request like this  i.imgur.com/j4H8oPQ.png
but comment every thing in your controller method **update**  and just use something like  `return response()->json($request->all())`

Comment: i commented all and paste your code and that return me 200 code with laravel home page

Comment: set header **Accept: application/json**.
So this means you are not getting parameters in controller method, that's why user is not updating.

Comment: yeah, **Accept: application/json** worked for me. Now start work PUT/PATCH method and without  **_method**

Answer (score 0):

Try to romve $request->validated(); when you use custom valdation class then 
there is no need to call validated() method

```
public function update(StoreUser $request, $id)
{
$request->validated();
$user = User::find($id);
$user->update($request->all());
return response()->json($user, 200);
}

use following code
public function update(StoreUser $request, User $user)
{
$user->update($request->all());
return response()->json($user, 200);
}
```

In above code User $user use as parameter its mean that route model binding so 
there is no need to use extra query to find user

Comment: when i call update method at first it go to StoreUser request and it's cause error and by this reason no one line of code not calling in update method

Comment: What sort of issue occure?

Comment: [error image](http://i.imgur.com/I5WU52a.png) same error as before writing my question

Comment: i try with password and without it, any way i catch error

Comment: return response([
            'Message:' => 'UserUpdted Sucessfully',
            'data' => $user
        ],Response::HTTP_CREATED);
try this